# Maximizing Profits

Tags: calculus, optimization

A TV set costs $100. If its price is lowered by a%, the sales would
increase by 2a%. Find the discount amount a which yields the maximal
profit.

The answer is 25%, but I'm not how to get this. Here is the equation I came up with:

Profit = 100 (1 - a/100) * [2x (1 + a/100)]

Comment: is that "2x" a multiplication $2 \times$ or a double a variable $2x$ ?

Comment: 2x is twice the variable

Comment: why do you even have x wtf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The profit is $\displaystyle (100-a)\left(1+\frac{2a}{100}\right)$.

The first parentheses is the price, the second is the sales percent.

Expanding this gives $\displaystyle -\frac{a^2}{50}+a+100$.

Taking the derivative with respect to $a$ gives $\displaystyle -\frac{a}{25}+1$.

The derivative is equal to $0$ when $a=25$, and the derivative goes from positive to negative at $a=25$, therefore it is a maximum.

Therefore, the discount amount maximizing profit is $\boxed{25\%}$.

Answer (score 0):

The percentage change in the profit is

\begin{align}
\left[\left(1-\frac{a}{100}\right)\left(1+\frac{2a}{100}\right)-1\right]\times100\%&=\frac{100a-2a^2}{100}\%\\
&=\frac{1250-2(25-a)^2}{100}\%\\
\end{align}

which is maximized when $a=25$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

In effect you want to maximise $(1-a)(1+2a)$  or, if you must work in percentages, $(1-\frac{a}{100})(1+\frac{2a}{100})$

Differentiate, find the zero, check it really is a maximimum